# how to build a tree for ordered numbers?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying build a  tree (dictionary ) from input numbers. My main criteria for the tree is all the nodes in a level are in a same range. ( a series of data from parent) I think  you will get idea from my examples-

Please see the example

```
    input_list=[1,2,3,4,5,
        5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,
        6,7,8,8.1,8.2,8.21,
        8.22,8.22,8.23,8.24,8.25,
        8.3,8.4,8.5,
        9,9.1,9.2,9.3,10,11,12]

    expected_out_put={
        0: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
        5: [5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4],
        8: [8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5],
        8.2: [8.21,8.22,8.23,8.24,8.25],
        9: [9.1,9.2,9.3],
    }
```

I tried to build a tree initially. This will work only for the data 1-9, anybody help me to find a better solution
This is how I tried

```
    class Section:
        FIRST_TIME=False
        def intialise(self):
            self.rank=0
            self.child_sections.clear()
            self.next_value_diff=10000
            parent=None
        def __init__(self,**Kwargs): 
            self.rank = Kwargs['rank']
            self.child_sections=[]
            self.next_value_diff=0
        def set_next_value_diff(self,value):
            self.next_value_diff=value
            
        def is_sibling(self,section_obj):
            c_diff=abs(section_obj.rank-self.rank)
            print('c_difference is '+str(c_diff)+"and prev differnec is"+str(self.next_value_diff))
            if(self.next_value_diff>c_diff):
                return False
            return True
            
        def add_child(self,section_obj):
            prev_root=self
            print("Self rank is"+str(self.rank))
            print(len(self.child_sections))
            print([i.rank for i in self.child_sections])
    
            if(len(self.child_sections)>0):
                prev_root=self.child_sections[-1]
                
            c_diff=abs(section_obj.rank-prev_root.rank)    
            print("addred rank "+str(section_obj.rank)+" prev "+str(prev_root.rank)+"diffrenc "+str(c_diff))
      
            
            section_obj.next_value_diff=c_diff
            self.child_sections.append(section_obj)
            print("added "+str(section_obj.rank)+"under "+str(self.rank)+"diffrenc "+str(c_diff))
            return 
        
    data_stack=[1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 2.1, 2.11, 2.12, 2.13, 2.14, 2.15, 2.16, 2.17, 2.18, 2.19, 2.2, 2.21, 2.22, 2.23, 2.24, 2.25, 2.26, 2.27, 2.28, 2.34, 2.35, 2.36, 2.37, 2.38, 2.39, 2.4, 2.42, 2.43, 2.44, 2.45, 2.46]
    data_stack=[i*1000 for i in data_stack]
    data_stack.reverse()
    print(data_stack)
    def create_root(parent):
        print('Current parent is'+str(parent.rank))
        global data_stack
        while( (len(data_stack)>0) and (not parent.is_sibling(Section(rank=data_stack[-1])))):
            rank_value=data_stack.pop()
            print("poped value of "+str(rank_value))
            section_obj=Section(rank=rank_value)      
            if(len(parent.child_sections)>0):
                print("Found its  "+str(parent.rank)+"has "+str(len(parent.child_sections))+" childrens")
                #check any child exists
                #sub_section is a sibling
                child=parent.child_sections[-1]
                print("checking simplinag "+str(section_obj.rank)+" : aginst child "+str(child.rank))
              
                if child.is_sibling(section_obj):
                    print("yes he is simpler with "+str(rank_value)+" : aginst child "+str(child.rank))
                    parent.add_child(section_obj)               
                else:
                    print('not sibler')
                    nextparent=parent.child_sections.pop()
                    print('popped '+str(nextparent.rank))
                    print("Koids")
                    print([i.rank for i in nextparent.child_sections])
                    nextparent.add_child(section_obj)
    
                    print('recurent call happenmd')
                    parent.add_child(create_root(nextparent))
                    
            else:
                print("No child at the time of"+str(rank_value))
                parent.add_child(section_obj)
                print("added to parent at the time of"+str(rank_value))
        return parent
        
        
    parent=Section(rank=0)
    parent.intialise()
    parent=create_root(parent)
    print(parent.rank)
    print([j.rank for j in parent.child_sections])
    for k in parent.child_sections:
        print('kids of'+str(k.rank))
        print([m.rank for m in k.child_sections])
        for m in k.child_sections:
            print('kids of'+str(m.rank))
            print([n.rank for n in m.child_sections])
            for n in m.child_sections:
                print('kids of'+str(n.rank))
                print([s.rank for s in n.child_sections])
```

Comment: But why does '0' contain '8' in the list of values and after that, there is and '8' as key?

Comment: Dictionary contains parent as key , child as value of list, root node is '0'  its children are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 .  in that tree 8 will have children [8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5]

Comment: mhm, yes, the floor is made out of floor. What is the logic behind this classification? Why is 8 in 0? Why isn't it in 8?

Comment: Okey..  I could say my problem to solve.  . I have an index page of document , its like 
1
2
3
4
 4.1
 4.2
 4.3
5
 5.1
 5.2
6
7
8
Document and subsection are listed in index . I need to parse the document based on the index. ..it may contain main topic and subtopics. We need to parse subtopic as children of man topic in our tree,I need to parse all this as a content tree. Part of that problem i was trying to build that.

Comment: Why is 5.1 missing from the output?

Comment: @DaniMesejo sorry, That was my mistake, Thanks to point out it

Comment: Float numbers are a bad representation for your problem

Comment: OKey - Actually i am dealing that after multiplying that with 1000. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: What is your initial input, strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt:

**Imports**: I'm working with `defaultdict` and `groupby`,  both from the standard library:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
```

Two **helper functions** for later:

```
def tuple_to_key(tup):
    if len(tup) == 2:
        return int(tup[0])
    return float(f"{tup[0]}.{''.join(n for n in tup[1:-1])}")

def childs_to_float(childs):
    return [float(f"{tup[0]}.{''.join(n for n in tup[1:])}") for tup in childs]
```

**Step 1**: Establishing the levels (the assumption is that `input_list` is sorted):

```
levels = defaultdict(list)
for tup in [(lst[0],) if len(lst) == 1 else (lst[0],) + tuple(lst[1])
            for lst in [str(n).split('.') for n in input_list]]:
    levels[len(tup)].append(tup)
```

The result looks like:

```
{
 1: [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',), ('7',), ('8',), ('9',), ('10',), ('11',), ('12',)],
 2: [('5', '1'), ('5', '2'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4'),
     ('8', '1'), ('8', '2'), ('8', '3'), ('8', '4'), ('8', '5'),
     ('9', '1'), ('9', '2'), ('9', '3')],
 3: [('8', '2', '1'), ('8', '2', '2'), ('8', '2', '2'), ('8', '2', '3'), ('8', '2', '4'), ('8', '2', '5')]
}
```

**Step 2**: Finding the parent child relationships:

```
output = {
    parent: childs_to_float(childs)
    for level in levels.keys() if level > 1
    for parent, childs in groupby(levels[level], key=tuple_to_key)
}
if 1 in levels:
    childs = [int(t[0]) for t in levels[1]]
    output[min(childs) - 1] = childs
```

**Output**:

```
{
 0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 5: [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4],
 8: [8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5],
 8.2: [8.21, 8.22, 8.22, 8.23, 8.24, 8.25],
 9: [9.1, 9.2, 9.3]
}
```

I'm sure there are plenty of wrinkles in it ...

Comment: Great..You made my day.  This is what I was looking for.Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

First you get the keys, which are zero plus the unique integer parts of the list elements:

```
keys=set(map(lambda x: 0 if isinstance(x, int) else int(x), input_list))
```

That should give you

```
{0, 5, 8, 9}
```

Then, you could produce the dictionary of int, list in several ways, for example:

```
{k: [y for y in input_list if (k==0 and isinstance(y, int)) or (k>0 and not isinstance(y, int) and int(y)==k)] for k in keys}
```

It is a dictionary generated with your keys and, inside, all the lists selecting only those elements that match the requirement (integer or key.decimal)

Comment: Thanks for your help . But we can't say all the key are integer. for example , for 1.1 may have children 1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14